DKIM record not being verified by Resend
I will be honest and DNS settings are somewhat a weak point of mine so please forgive me any ignorance/stupidity on my part.
I have a domain that is currently sending transactional emails via Mailersend and I am looking to migrate to Resend, ideally with both in place at first but once I test Resend is working remove Mailersend.
My site is hosted on Vercel and the domain is registered through Fasthosts. I initially put the three DNS records in Fasthosts and then realised it should be Vercel, so I removed them from FH and added them to Vercel. It eventually verified two of them, but the DKIM isn't verifying. Thinking it might be I need it on FH (I struggle to understand what should go where so tends to be trial and error) but that still isn't working.
However its been a few days and that isn't working and I think it should be in Vercel anyway. The existing DKIM record is in Vercel and has a different name so I don't think its conflicting, but I can't figure out why the DKIM record is the only one that can't be verified.
Using tools (including easydmarc which Resends recommends) the value seems to be okay, but the verification isn't working and its been a few days now.
I doubt its this but the only difference I can see between what Resend recommends and what I've done is they suggest TTL should be auto and as Vercel doesn't allow that I've chosen 60 but other than that it is exactly the same.
Any recommendations on what I should be looking out for would be much appreciated.

Without the domain to check for the DNS, I think it is hard to debug this one... Check the records with DIG to ensure they are in the correct name.

Ah fair, wasn't sure how useful it would be given you wouldn't be able to see what Resend recommended but someone suggested deleting and trying again and that worked. Thank you for your help.

I have been needing to do the same thing. I had an old Next.js application on Next 11 with Nodemailer and Node/Express, this setup no longer worked with Next14 so I wanted to migrate to Resend using Route Handlers to send Emails.  I have spent my morning with the same issue. I ended up deleting the domain a few times but added the records and DKIM record like this in my registrar
MX
send.yourdomain.com
TXT
send.yourdomain.com
TXT
resend._domainkey.yourdomain.com
The first two records verified quickly and the DKIM in about 12-15 minutes.
I have not tested email sending yet, but my domain is at least verified!
I hope it helps.

Thanks, that seemed to work! Verified straight away after doing that.

Had the same issue, coming from nodemailer that doesn't work for who knows how long.. just noticed. Wanted to migrate to resend, and worked on it yesterday, waiting to be verified.. one got verified, but by this morning all failed..time wasted. Deleted the domain from resend and vercel, recreated the same way, and got verified in 5 seconds.. :D Thanks @eckosneekz

If you have an existing spf record (usually when you have outlook set up or any other email provider) you need to combine both spf records.
In my case, I had outlook configured in my dns records and adding another TXT spf record didn't work until I merged them using this tool which I found after finding this video two days later which solved the error.
I was getting a: "We can't verify that this email came from the sender so it might not be safe to respond to it." error message.

Is it required to merge the records? They are scoped to different domains, Outlook to root domain (example.com) and Resend to send.example.com

@knorthfield yes, you should only have one record so if you need more entries you should merge them.
PS: The DNS settings that i was working with already had many entries in the same spf record, i just added the resend one. Have you managed to get it working?
